# Field is required on foreign key error Django rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I am in a issue in which my api is creating a duplicate data as I am just passing ingredient name and its restaurant not Pk etc. So to prevent this thing I made a

```
class Meta:
     unique_together = ('restaurant' ,'name')
```

constraint in my model . Before this everything was fine just duplicate entries were creating. Now after adding this constraint its saying 'Restaurant field is required'  and my serializer is not valid.

**My Ingredient model is like this**

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255 ,)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('restaurant' ,'name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

**and my Ingredient Serializer is like**

```
class IngredientsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    restaurant = RestaurantSerializer(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        restaurant = validated_data.get('restaurant')
        name = validated_data.get('name', None)
        ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create(restaurant=restaurant, name=name)
        return ingredient
```

And my view.py for serialize is like

```
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
class CreateIngredients(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = IngredientsSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            restaurant=Restaurant.objects.get(id=request.POST['restaurant'])
            obj_article = serializer.save(restaurant=restaurant)
        return Response(success_response(data='none', msg='Ingredient added'), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I am not clear what are you doing by ```restaurant=Restaurant.objects.get(id=request.POST['restaurant'])
            obj_article = serializer.save(restaurant=restaurant)```?

Comment: @ruddra  as I am getting id in   request  and by Id I am getting restaurant object from data base and then saving it as I can't pass restaurant object in   data=request.data .   Is there any good way to do this ? like passing foregin key data in  request.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not sending `restaurant` in your request.

Even though in your serializer you've defined that restaurant isn't required.

```
restaurant = RestaurantSerializer(required=False)
```

What makes it invalid is the `create` method. In there you have

```
ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create(restaurant=restaurant, name=name)
```

which uses objects create method (your restaurant argument here is probably `None`) and since you've defined unique together with `restaurant` and `name` this means neither of them can be `None`.

Comment: In   data=request.data    there is  restaurant id I am sending  which is foreign key field. how I can send  foregin key field in request.data then

Comment: basically what would be right way to do this ? @Toni

Comment: @toni What would be the solution? I see this as a good explanation of what is going on, but not an answer...